# How to update Raku documentations which p6doc will read?

Tags: raku

On mac, I have installed rakudo-star 2023.02 from Homebrew. Then I tried to `zef install rakudoc`, but it aborted installing due to test failures. It seems that the development of `rakudoc` had stalled for quite a while. So I `zef install p6doc`, and happily read raku documentations without bothering to leave terminal's window, just to find that the documents `p6doc` uses are out-of-date.

The docs have been installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/rakudo-star/2023.02/share/perl6/site/doc`. I went to https://github.com/Raku/doc to get the latest doc directory and replace my old doc directory with the downloaded one, then rebuilt p6doc's index with `p6doc build`. But `p6doc` won't use the new docs such that when I `p6doc Str`, it says `No such type 'Str'`.

How do I update the docs p6doc reads to the latest ones? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

p6doc is no longer current; [rakudoc](https://github.com/raku/rakudoc) is the current incarnation of the command line tool.

I was able to read the `Str` docs on the command line, with the following steps (with a local clone of each repo):

```
$ cd ~/sandbox
$ git clone git@github.com:Raku/rakudoc.git
$ git clone git@github.com:Raku/doc.git
$ cd rakudoc
$ zef install --deps-only .
$ RAKUDOC=~/sandbox/doc raku -I. bin/rakudoc -D -b # Indexing 417...
$ RAKUDOC=~/sandbox/doc raku -I. bin/rakudoc -D Type/Str # TITLE class Str
```

`zef install rakudoc` as of right now is missing some bugfixes on HEAD. You could `zef install .` from a git clone to get the unreleased working version, and I've opened [a ticket](https://github.com/Raku/rakudoc/issues/24) to get a new release moving.

Looks like the big difference is you currently need Type/Str.

**EDIT**:

We had the env var pointing at the wrong folder, and I've cut a new release, so we can install via zef:

```
$ zef install rakudoc
$ cd ~/sandbox
$ git clone git@github.com:Raku/doc.git
$ RAKUDOC=~/sandbox/doc/doc rakudoc -D -b # Indexing 417...
$ RAKUDOC=~/sandbox/doc/doc rakudoc -D Str # TITLE class Str
$ RAKUDOC=~/sandbox/doc/doc rakudoc -D .polymod #all polymod methods
```

Comment: Coke, I appreciate your kind help. After running the commands you provide, now I can read Type/Str doc, but rakudoc still doesn't know `Str`, `Str.tans` or `open` etc. It seems that we have to provide the path `Type/Str` then rakudoc knows to go to Type directory to get the Str doc. If so, we just have to p6doc <fullpath>/Str.rakudoc to open and read the latest doc file without all the work of trying to install rakudoc from github.

Comment: Thanks, added a bug report to the github repo to track this issue.

Comment: @AlvaPan If you are able to accept this answer that would be nice given that the bug is also now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Coke and @raiph, thanks a lot for your perseverant devotion to Raku and great help to me. Now it works as I have expected. At present, I install rakudoc using git clone as Coke instructs me to. Hopefully, we will be able to `zef install rakudoc` soon.

Comment: Added another edit - installing via zef should work now for rakudoc. Enjoy.