# How to read the docs with rakudoc?

Tags: raku, zef

I just installed rakudoc with zef.  But it doesn't seem to find any
doc.

```
$ rakudoc --version
/home/user/.raku/bin/rakudoc :auth<zef:coke>:api<1>:ver<0.2.6>
$ rakudoc -b
$ rakudoc Map
No results for 'Map'
```

My operating system is Fedora 38.  Zef and rakudoc are not available
from my distro's repositories.  So I installed the `rakudo-pkg` package
from Cloudsmith.  Then I ran `install-zef` as my non-root user to
install zef for my user.  Then I ran `zef install rakudoc` to install
rakudoc.  I also tried to have it index what seem like where the source
is:

```
rakudoc -b -d /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6
rakudoc -b -d /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/core
rakudoc -b -d /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/core/sources
```

I also tried to install rakudoc in the `rakudo-star` docker image.  In
the container I ran:

```
zef install rakudoc
rakudoc --version
/usr/share/perl6/site/bin/rakudoc :auth<zef:coke>:api<1>:ver<0.2.6>
rakudoc -b
```

I still got:

```
No results for 'Map'
```

So.  How do I read the docs on the command line?

Comment: Does [this recent answer to a `rakudoc` question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75679208/1077672), which led to @coke cutting a release that he implied should work on a system including Fedora 36 [here](https://github.com/Raku/rakudoc/issues/16), help?

Comment: @raiph I see.  So simply installing rakudoc from zef does not give me the doc for the builtins even though the help text when I run rakudoc with no arguments seems to imply I can look up `Map`.  In that case I would rather go to the web site for docs than installing it locally from source.  The bug you mentioned seems to be fixed.  I didn't run into any problem when I installed rakudoc except that it didn't give me the doc.

Comment: "I didn't run into any problem when I installed `rakudoc` except that it didn't give me the doc."  Seriously, thanks for the comment -- I neither use nor know much about the `rakudoc` tool, so I've learned from your reply. Sounds like, at the very least, the help text is misleading. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/Raku/rakudoc/issues/28) about that. I know that the whole doc setup is in flux right now and @coke only just took on `rakudoc`. Maybe you've encountered things in a halfway state? It might be helpful if you add your own 2c to the issue I just filed and/or subscribe to it.